# Laravel 6: Save data to Pivot Table

Tags: php, laravel-6.2

I have Table `Sale` and `Product` that link `many-to-many` to each other.

**In `Product Schema`**

```
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            ...
            $table->double('price');
           ....
        });
```

**`in product_sale Schema`**

```
Schema::create('product_sale', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('sale_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity')->default(1);
            $table->double('unit_price');
            $table->integer('discount')->nullable()->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('sale_id')->references('id')->on('sales')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('set null');
        });
```

Of course, i want to query `price` from product to save to `unit_price` in `product_sale` table..

I wonder, is there a way that i can archieve that??

**`And Here in SaleController`**

```
       if(isset($request->items)) {
            foreach($request->items as $item) {
                $sale->products()->attach($item['id'], [
                    'unit_price' => $item['unit_price'],
                    'quantity' => $item['quantity'],
                    'discount' => $item['discount'],
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi. Can you clarify the exact problem you are facing. It's a bit vague. If you're trying to save data to the pivot table, your current code in your controller ( attach ) should work if you've set up relationships properly and there's nothing going wrong elsewhere.